# Can Anti-Particle like Anti-Proton give advantage in ADS (Accelerator Driven System) for Neutralizing Nuclear Waste?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, antimatter, nuclear-engineering

I was going through a thesis of Adonai Martinez for ["Transmutation of Nuclear Waste in Accelerator-Driven Systems"](https://cds.cern.ch/record/849079/) published in 2004.

I saw he used Proton for ADS but it occured to me that, Anti-Particles are better in conveying energy that's one of the reason Scientists are looking forward its usecase in Cancer. Can there be any advantage of using Anti-Particles in ADS system than Proton?

Also, If someone can answer this question too. As both are inter-connected! Does using Pion or Muon also gives any advantage in ADS than using Proton?

Answer (score 1):

I [found Accelerator-driven Nuclear Energy](https://world-nuclear.org/information-library/current-and-future-generation/accelerator-driven-nuclear-energy.aspx)

> The transmutation of long-lived radioactive waste can be carried out in an accelerator-driven system (ADS), *where neutrons* produced by an accelerator are directed at a blanket assembly containing the waste along with fissionable fuel. Following neutron capture, the heavy isotopes in the blanket assembly subsequently fission, producing energy in doing so. ADSs could also be used to generate power from the abundant element thorium.

Italic mine.

Note that the objective of the beam of protons is to produce secondary neutrons by the proton interactions on the material, and it is the neutrons that participate in the fission process.

> a beam of high-energy protons (usually >500 MeV) is directed at a high-atomic number target (e.g. tungsten, tantalum, depleted uranium, thorium, zirconium, lead, lead-bismuth, mercury) and up to one neutron can be produced per 25 MeV of the incident proton beam. (These numbers compare with 200-210 MeV released by the fission of one uranium-235 or plutonium-239 atomb.) A 1000 MeV beam will create 20-30 spallation neutrons per proton.

It is easier to produce proton beams so, even though antiprotons might also have competitive neutrons by $spallation^*$, there is extra effort in producing the beam. The final objective is to have a number of neutrons come out so that fission can be induced.

As for pions and muons, because they decay, extra effort is needed  to control the beam, also muons interact only with the electromagnetic and weak interactions so could not induce spallation on nuclei to get a competitive number of neutrons.

---

*[spallation](https://www.britannica.com/science/spallation), high-energy nuclear reaction in which a target nucleus struck by an incident (bombarding) particle of energy greater than about 50 million electron volts (MeV) ejects numerous lighter particles and becomes a product nucleus correspondingly lighter than the original nucleus. The light ejected particles may be neutrons, protons, or various composite particles equivalent to nuclei of hydrogen, helium, or lithium isotopes.

Comment: Mhmm! Does there any industry standard value exist for Proton beam to create certain amount of spallation? ( I mean value that both economically and technically well-enough and can reduce the halflife of radio waste effectively) 

If not! Can you mention what type of trend should be followed in beam energy level for  ADS to effectively neutralize nulcear waste?

Comment: I think it is still a matter of research. the link just gives indications of what has been achieved up to now.

Comment: after analyzing your answer. I had a question, What kind of target (tungsten, tantalum or lead and vice versa) is useful to attain a good amount of neutrons?

Comment: @TAWSIFAHMED Sorry, this is not my field. I answered your question because I  did not know anything about it and tried to learn by asking on google, reading the information article I linked above. If you are  really interested you should try to dig up the references in the link, and try to contact the researchers directly,which is what I would do if I were interested to go into this subject.